# Error 10013 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, apache, sockets, flask, mod-wsgi

Please, help me. I cannot run my simple Flask app (Hello world) on Apache server due to an error 10013:
**An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.**

I have Windows 11 x64.
I have Python 3.10.9, flask 2.2.2, Apache 2.4.54, mod_wsgi 4.9.4.
Antivirus: ESET 10.0.2045.0

What I want: run Flask app on Apache server via mod_wsgi.
Now, my app is running on WSGIserver and it is OK. But I want running via Apache and I get still same error 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket blablabla...

Mod_wsgi is installed and implemented in Apache httpd.conf:

```
LoadFile "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310"

#WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp python-path="c:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages"

<VirtualHost *:8000>
#   DocumentRoot "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world"

    <Directory c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world/app.wsgi"

</VirtualHost>
```

WSGI Module is loaded, it's OK. VirtualHost and listening are set on port 8000.

I checked configuration of Apache and error log. Everything seems to be fine. Apache is running and without WSGImodule Apache web page is displayed.

I was looking for solution. So...

1. Port 8000 is already in use? No, 8000 is free for app.
2. I disabled Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) in Services in Control panels. Nothing changed.
3. I disabled Firewall and network and PC protection in ESET. Nothing changed. (I know that's not a good solution.)
4. I tried connect over Python module socket with localhost on port 8000 but my experiment ended with WinError 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

My hello world app runs on Werkzeug and on WSGIserver server.

Code of webapp:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

index.html is simple webpage with heading: Hello world.

Code of app.wsgi:

```
#! C:/Users/pvachal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world")

activate_this = "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world/venv/scripts/activate_this.py"
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from app import app as application
```

But... this app.wsgi won't start anyway.
I've been trying to fix it for the last week but it won't work. I think problem is with network protection. Yes, I know that thinking is wishing dinging :^)

Where is the problem? How can I run my app on Apache server?

Comment: I uninstalled ESET and turned off Firewall but it still didn't work. Connection to the socket works but running on Apache server doesn't work. Same errors, same problems. Please, help me.

Comment: Ok, IT ladies and IT gentlemen,
I will try learn how to use sockets and how work with them, from page:
https://realpython.com/python-sockets/
and after that learning I will write feedback here.

Comment: **SOLVED.**
I solved my problem with Mister Dumpleton's help: [link](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/828)

In httpd must be: WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/flask_app_hello_world/app.wsgi" application-group=%{GLOBAL}
After that rewrite app.wsgi runs correctly and **everything is OK**.

Comment: And my app runs even with antivirus turned on. This means that the antivirus didn't affect it (we are talking about ESET and built-in firewall).